# Clicking in UISearchBar causes memory leak

Tags: iphone, uitableview, memory-management, uisearchbar

I have been getting a weird memory leak and i just pinpointed what is causing.  I am using a utility application that has a main view and a flipside view.  When you are on the flipside view you are able to present another modal view by clicking a plus button.  This view has a UISearchBar and UITableView.  When clicking on the UISearchBar a memory leak is produced with the following information:

[alt text http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/6175/picture4ux.png](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/6175/picture4ux.png)

Why does clicking in this bar produce that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: image is unnecessary. it will be much better if you post some code. for example, your searchBarShouldBeginEditing. also you should make time between checking memory for leaks smaller. you have 10 seconds now. are you sure that memory leak appears after clicking on your searchbar? maybe it appeared few seconds before. for example, after creating new controller....

Comment: I actually hit the check leaks button after the controller is instantiated and right after I click in the search bar.  And I don't have the searchBarShouldBeginEditing function defined right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the same leak when using an NSXMLParser, I have multiple apps that have been approved with the same behavior, and I have yet to have any crashes in any of the Apps.

I've heard that the leak is misreported by instruments, but I haven't take the time to verify.